# how to manage loading dll's before entering main() function in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, dll

How does the Visual C++ program load dll's before entering the main function in visual studio express 2008? In a project developed by others a dll was loaded by "a.ext:native" but I don't know how is this configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to instruct the OS to load a DLL.  The most common way is to link to a .lib file (through the project's linker settings), where the .lib is a build-time stub associated with the DLL.  When the linker finds this .lib file during the linking stage, it knows that the DLL is required, and modifies the EXE internally to tell the operating system that the DLL must exist in order for the program to run.

When the program is later run, the operating system first looks for all required DLL's - even before beginning to execute the code for the program.  If any of these DLL's are missing, the operating system throws an error, an error box pops up, and the program will not run.

It's also possible to dynamically load a DLL, but this isn't all that common.

Comment: Dynamically loading a DLL is actually *quite* common. There are two common use cases that come to mind: 1) a plug-in system, and 2) supporting additional functionality that is only available in later versions of Windows, while retaining backwards-compatibility with older versions (e.g., the DWM APIs defined in `dwmapi.dll`).

Comment: Fair enough - I've done plenty of dynamic loading of DLL's myself.  Not sure what percentage of DLL's are typically statically, vs. dynamically, loaded, other than my impression.

Comment: My question is really about the static loading. ---- How is the loading of the DLL's controlled in the .lib ? through source code or configuration?

Comment: It is controlled entirely by the structure of the .lib.  The linker looks at the internal structure of the .lib (at build time) and sees that the functions are declared but not defined (this is completely internal to the .lib); then the linker builds special instructions into the .exe, telling the operating system that when the .exe runs, a DLL by that name must exist and must have functions that match.  None of this is controlled by source code.  It is a *linker* setting to pass the .lib to the linker.

Comment: >>Dan N, thanks. And the structure of the .lib is controlled when it's generated, is this correct? Maybe 2 options can exist:
1. the implementation of the functions can be in the .lib;
2. the implementation of the functions can be in an associated .dll with the same name as the .lib.
Or any other options?

Comment: The structure of the .lib is determined at the time the library itself is built.  If the library is being built as a "dynamic library", then the compiler creates two output files, a .dll and an associated .lib - the latter to be used by clients of the library as a necessary stub file in order for client programs to be able to build.  If the library is built as a "static library", then the only output file is a .lib, containing *all* function definitions, not just stubs.

Comment: @Dan Nissenbaum >>>>>>The linker looks at the internal structure of the .lib (at build time) and sees that the functions are declared but not defined (this is completely internal to the .lib); then ...... If a function is declared but not defined won't the linker report an error?? At least for source code building this is the case.  And is it possible that a global variable that is declared in a DLL be referenced in the application that loads it?

Comment: The linker is smart enough to know that when linking to a .lib representing a dynamic library that the function _declarations_ are sufficient. In terms of global variables defined in the DLL, these must be declared (but not defined) just like functions in a dynamic .lib stub must be declared but not defined - in the case of variables the `extern` keyword is used in the .lib's header files that are also included in the main app that links to that .lib; the library source code (.cpp) file (compiled to the DLL) then defines the variable (without the `extern` keyword).